# magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am trying to install the extension through composer, but I am getting the below error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

```shell
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

**Problem 2**

```shell
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

**Problem 3**

```shell
- laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin 1.0.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.4].
- magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

```
You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.

For more information please find the below image.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was struggling with the same error recently. I downgraded Composer to 1.9 and deleted my composer.lock file, it resolved that error you are having.

Downgrade composer:

1. Uninstall composer
2. Follow the instructions here: https://getcomposer.org/download/
   with the exception of using the download link for 1.9.3
   (https://getcomposer.org/download/1.9.3/composer.phar)

Remove composer.lock file:

There is a file called composer.lock in your Magento root folder. Delete it or move it just in case.

Then just run the command you did before.

Comment: How can i downgraded composer and how to deletecomposer.lock-file

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Thanks. I didn't download it directly, I added the version parameter instead to get 1.9.3 (php composer-setup.php --version=1.9.3).

Comment: Any solution for windows

Comment: For the issue that I had, the secret was removing the composer.lock file

Answer (score 17):

It seems your are using unsupported composer version.

Check the current composer version with:

```
composer -V
```

The 1.0.0 version of magento/composer-root-update-plugin requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0, so it's not compatible with Composer2. You can check out repository in more detail [here](https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/tree/1.0.0).

If you just recently updated the composer you can run a rollback

```
composer self-update --rollback
```

Or install the latest release of version 1:

```
composer self-update --1
```

If you are updating Magento please check out the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Add `--ignore-platform-reqs` at end of your composer command, may it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue during a Magento update 2.3.2 to 2.3.4 and found that composer 2 is only compatible with specific version of Magento 2 https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

I did update to the latest version of composer 1 by using command
`php composer-setup.php --version=1.10.22`

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific error I worked around without having to downgrade composer.
Run composer update with flag --ignore-platform-reqs

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

once Magento is upgraded (in my case to 2.4.4), now composer update without ignore flag works as normal.