# composer showing error when i install a plugin on magento 2.2.11

Tags: magento2, composer

I am doing as below:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp72/bin/php composer.phar require facebook/php-business-sdk --no-plugins
```

its showing error as:

```
Using version ^13.0 for facebook/php-business-sdk
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update facebook/php-business-sdk
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/magento-composer-installer 0.1.13 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.2.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.11 requires magento/magento-composer-installer >=0.1.11 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-composer-installer[0.1.13].
    - magento/product-community-edition is locked to version 2.2.11 and an update of this package was not requested.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require facebook/php-business-sdk:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require facebook/php-business-sdk:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

please help

Comment: You need to downgrade your composer version to 1.x [magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325287/magento-composer-root-update-plugin-is-locked-to-version-1-0-0-and-an-update-of)

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk thanks, you saved my lots of time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below and check it.

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp72/bin/php composer.phar require facebook/php-business-sdk --no-plugins --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: by doing this now magento stop working

Comment: facebook/php-business-sdk installed or not?

Comment: facebook/php-business-sdk installed

Comment: Please execute upgrade and deploy command and then check it.

Comment: yes i did but its look like composer version issues, i am going to downgrade composer to 1.~